# Tumblr V2 API PHP wrapper

Tags: php, blogs, tumblr

I am trying to integrate a Tumblr blog into my website, using the TumblrPHP wrapper available at https://github.com/gregavola/tumblrPHP. This is code I'm using to view the posts on my site:

```
<?php
    include ('lib/tumblrPHP.php');
    $consumer = 'key';
    $secret = 'key';
    $tumblr = new Tumblr($consumer, $secret);
    $posts = $tumblr->get('/blog/nyhetergaius.tumblr.com/posts');
    foreach($posts->response->posts as $posts) {
    ?>
        <h2><?php echo date('Y-m-d', $post->timestamp) ?></h2>
        <?php if ($post['type'] == 'regular') { ?>
        <?php echo $post{'body'}; ?>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if ($post->type == 'photo') {
            foreach ($post->photos as $photo) {
                ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $photo->alt_sizes[1]->url ?>" />
                <?php
            }
            echo $post->caption;
        }
        else
            echo $post->body;
        ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I am using my own key and secret key, but even so I can only retrieve a default date for each post. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to view the posts as they appear on the blog http://nyhetergaius.tumblr.com/? This is how the posts appear on my site:  http://test.gaius.nu/om.php.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by replacing $post['type'] with $post->type etc..

```
foreach($posts->response->posts as $posts) {
    $postDate = date('Y-m-d', $posts->timestamp);
    echo "<h2>$postDate</h2>";
    if ($posts->type == 'regular') {
        echo $posts->body;
    }
    elseif ($posts->type == 'photo') {
        foreach ($posts->photos as $photo) {
            $imgURL = $photo->alt_sizes[1]->url;
            echo "<img src=\"$imgURL\" />";
        }
        echo $posts->caption;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $posts->body;
    }
}
```